# Odoo 12: How to use form values in @api.model methods

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-12

I am new in the forum.
I am currently working with Odoo 12 and I'm having some problems communicating Odoo Model with my Javascript Widget. Step by step...
1. I am creating a widget that shows some Google Charts and the only way I've found was to show the QWeb code in a custom view and assign the Widget to a Char field.
2. I've achieved a nice approach using rpc in my start: function using rpc and getting the data from the module.
3. THE PROBLEM:
I need to show two Date fields in the form and use that dates as an interval for my Google Charts: How can I get the date values in my @api.model
 function??
The function can only read a resultset of all the table, when I try to get the result (self.init_date) set in the field, I always receive "False"
Sorry, I can't post the code today, but on Monday I will post it if nobody can give me the answer.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `api.model` decorator gives you access to the model's methods but not to the records, so they can be called when the model has no records (See https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#module-odoo.api).

If the method you wrote is intended to always receive a record, just remove the `api.model` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to use something like this

```
from odoo import api,models, fields, _

class MyCustomModel(models.Model):
    _name = "my.custom.model"

    #... some fields
    date1 =  fields.Date(string="Date 1")
    date2 =  fields.Date(string="Date 2")

    @api.model
    def my_custom_func(self):
        # read all data in table
        all_records = self.env['my.custom.model'].search([])
        for rec in all_records:
            print(rec.date1, rec.date2)
```

this a simple example to access to date1 and date2 for all records